# Number-theoretic notation in Wolfram Cloud for iOS

Tags: series-expansion, wolfram-cloud, notation

I am using Wolfram Cloud Mathematica, and I want to write an equation using the mathematical symbols for `Sum` (like a capital sigma, but no the Greek letter) and `Product` (like capital pi but not the Greek letter), with the index written only below the symbol not above, in the number-theoretic style.

For example,

$$\prod _{a\leq n} f(a)$$

The closest I can come in Wolfram Cloud, using the super-limited virtual keyboard of IOS13, is

```
Product[f[a],{a<=n,n}]//TraditionalForm
```

But this isn’t quite what I want because: (1) I don’t want the `n` above the `Product` symbol; (2) I want the result in standard Wolfram Language form, not the italicised `TraditionalForm` which is un-editable in the Cloud app.

If I had a physical keyboard I’d type Esc-prod-Esc, then Ctrl-4 to write the index below the symbol, then Ctrl-Space to write the main expression.

That’s not possible with IOS’s virtual keyboard. The ‘select’ function that in theory would allow me to remove the `n` above the product symbol simply doesn’t work in Wolfram Cloud for IOS: it won’t select just that one element, and even if it did, there is then no way to delete anything anyway.

Any suggestions?